# Show that any constant function between topological spaces is continuous

Tags: general-topology

> Show that any constant function between topological spaces is
>   continuous.

I am not sure how to begin this, I know that a function between topological spaces is continuous if the preimage of any open set is open.

Comment: it is not top ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:Under a constant map, the preimage of an open set is either empty or the full space.